# Python Pandas - How to limit row amount and automatically start new column

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

Go easy! I am a Python student! :)

I have a python program that simulates coin flips. The end result is that each coin flip is placed into a CSV as either -1 (tails) or 1 (heads). I need Pandas to limit the amount of rows per column to 1 million and to automatically continue to the next column after each 1 million rows. How would I go about this? I can't seem to find an applicable Pandas article and my knowledge on the subject is still very limited.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#get the flipcount
flipcount=int(input("How many times should I flip a coin?\n###:"))
samples = np.random.randint(0, 2, size = flipcount)

#create a pandas dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame([1 if i == 1 else -1 for i in samples])

#create a csv file
data.to_csv("data.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

Here is the newest attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#get the flipcount
flipcount=int(input("How many times should I flip a coin?\n###:"))

#create the data
samples = np.random.choice([-1, 1], size = flipcount)

# calculate the numbers of columns
n_columns = flipcount//10**6
if flipcount % 10**6 !=0:
    n_columns+=1

# create the DataFrame
mylist = [samples[(i-1)*mybreak:i*mybreak] for i in range(1, n_columns+1)]
data = pd.DataFrame(mylist).T

#create a csv file
data.to_csv("data789.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

Error in CMD

```
How many times should I flip a coin?
###:1001
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CoinFlipMania.py", line 16, in <module>
    mylist = [samples[(i-1)*mybreak:i*mybreak] for i in range(1, n_columns+1)]
  File "CoinFlipMania.py", line 16, in <listcomp>
    mylist = [samples[(i-1)*mybreak:i*mybreak] for i in range(1, n_columns+1)]
NameError: name 'mybreak' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
#create the data
samples = np.random.choice([-1, 1], size = flipcount)

# calculate the numbers of columns
n_columns = flipcount//10**6
if flipcount % 10**6 !=0:
    n_columns+=1

# create the DataFrame
mybreak = 1e6
mylist = [samples[(i-1)*mybreak:i*mybreak] for i in range(1, n_columns+1)]
data = pd.DataFrame(mylist).T
```

Comment: I have applied your code but I am unable to export to CSV. I have pasted my newest code above. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you export it?

Comment: Just realized I phrased the issue incorrectly. It is not working, hence not generating the CSV. 

Pasted it up above

Comment: The variable `mybreak` was not defined.  I changed my acode accordingly. I defined as 1 million.

Answer (score 1):

I think an approach like the following is easiest

```
flipcount = 2000001
my_break = 1000000

samples = np.random.choice([1, -1], size=flipcount)

if flipcount > my_break:
    n_empty = my_break - flipcount % my_break
    samples = np.append(samples, [np.nan] * n_empty).reshape((-1, my_break)).T

(pd.DataFrame(samples)
 .to_csv('my_csv.csv', index=False, header=False))
```